# Angular 2 development and browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, angular, caching

While developing an Angular 2 application, I use Google Chrome for debugging etc..

Problem is - any change I make, both in the `.js` files (`.ts` file) and in the HTML template files I use - is not visible, until I clear the browser's cache **manually**.

I've tried loading without cache (CTRL + F5), and changing the browser's setting to load new resources on every visit of my site, but this does not help.

When changing my index.html file, for instance, the problem doesn't occur.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: In the developer tools > settings > network, there is an option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)". Try enabling that? (and debug with the dev tools open obviously)

Comment: thanks @hdk. Please post this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the developer tools > settings > network, there is an option "Disable cache (while DevTools is open)".

[image]

Enable that setting and leave the developer tools open while debugging.